# Copy, Drag and Drop parcel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, drag-and-drop

Using 10.1 ArcGIS, how can you SELECT the parcel tract and MOVE IT to another part of the map? I have done that by accident in the past, but when I do need to do that, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open an Edit session
2. Select the parcel you want using the edit tool
3. Move to desired location

Comment: I just had to hover over the selected and just drag, thanks.